# Simple, casual open source OpenGL games to implement other things in

Tags: opengl, c++, open-source, casual-games

I am looking for a simple casual game (open source) done in openGL. I need it to implement communication component i build this is not for learning opengl  and to implement some other stuff into it. Where can I find one?
(I am using C++)
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I don't think reading another game's source code in isolation is going to help you learn much; there's a pretty severe lack of context in most code, so you won't know why particular programming design or implementation decisions were made. You can very easily pick up bad habits or the wrong idea.

That said, a s[imilar question has been asked here before](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1944/very-simple-open-source-games-in-various-languages). Also, here is a [list of open source games from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_open-source_video_games), and [this website](http://freegamer.blogspot.com/) is dedicated to open-source game development news and you might be able to find some examples there. Beyond that, it's a little difficult to provide what you've asked for since you haven't offered very many guidelines as to what you're trying to learn.

Comment: i didnt found any thing simple in the links , i need it not to learn opengl but to implement communication component i build

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1944/very-simple-open-source-games-in-various-languages). Not only C++, but you still should be able to get some ideas.

Comment: not looking for ideas